# The designer cannot process the code at line 115, please see the task list for details

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, designer

This is the error I get when I open the designer in VB.NET

> The designer cannot process the code at line 115, please see the task
>   list for details. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is
>   generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please
>   remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

http://prntscr.com/6e1fnq <- Screenshot

I have had this happen MANY times now.

Here's my designer code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class main
    Inherits MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(main))
        Me.Ctc1 = New DECrypt.CTC()
        Me.Crypter = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
        Me.FilePumper = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
        Me.rbtnMegaByte = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroRadioButton()
        Me.rbtnKiloByte = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroRadioButton()
        Me.txtFileName = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.btnPump = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.btnBrowse = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.NumericUpDown1 = New System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown()
        Me.Binder = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
        Me.IconChanger = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
        Me.About = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage()
        Me.MetroLabel3 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroLabel2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroLabel1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroButton1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.btn_File2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.btn_File1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.btn_Bind = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.TextBox1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.TextBox2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.Ctc1.SuspendLayout
        Me.FilePumper.SuspendLayout
        CType(Me.NumericUpDown1,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit
        Me.Binder.SuspendLayout
        Me.About.SuspendLayout
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'Ctc1
        '
        Me.Ctc1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.TabAlignment.Left
        Me.Ctc1.Controls.Add(Me.Crypter)
        Me.Ctc1.Controls.Add(Me.FilePumper)
        Me.Ctc1.Controls.Add(Me.Binder)
        Me.Ctc1.Controls.Add(Me.IconChanger)
        Me.Ctc1.Controls.Add(Me.About)
        Me.Ctc1.ItemSize = New System.Drawing.Size(30, 120)
        Me.Ctc1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 63)
        Me.Ctc1.Multiline = true
        Me.Ctc1.Name = "Ctc1"
        Me.Ctc1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Me.Ctc1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(511, 319)
        Me.Ctc1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.TabSizeMode.Fixed
        Me.Ctc1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Crypter
        '
        Me.Crypter.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 4)
        Me.Crypter.Name = "Crypter"
        Me.Crypter.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
        Me.Crypter.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(383, 311)
        Me.Crypter.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Crypter.Text = "Crypter"
        Me.Crypter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'FilePumper
        '
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.rbtnMegaByte)
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.rbtnKiloByte)
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.txtFileName)
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.btnPump)
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.btnBrowse)
        Me.FilePumper.Controls.Add(Me.NumericUpDown1)
        Me.FilePumper.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 4)
        Me.FilePumper.Name = "FilePumper"
        Me.FilePumper.Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
        Me.FilePumper.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(383, 311)
        Me.FilePumper.TabIndex = 1
        Me.FilePumper.Text = "File Pumper"
        Me.FilePumper.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'rbtnMegaByte
        '
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.AutoSize = true
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(15, 101)
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.Name = "rbtnMegaByte"
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(41, 15)
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.TabIndex = 5
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.Text = "MB"
        Me.rbtnMegaByte.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'rbtnKiloByte
        '
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.AutoSize = true
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(15, 59)
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.Name = "rbtnKiloByte"
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(37, 15)
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.TabIndex = 4
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.Text = "KB"
        Me.rbtnKiloByte.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'txtFileName
        '
        Me.txtFileName.Lines = New String(-1) {}
        Me.txtFileName.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 17)
        Me.txtFileName.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.txtFileName.Name = "txtFileName"
        Me.txtFileName.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0)
        Me.txtFileName.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.txtFileName.SelectedText = ""
        Me.txtFileName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(290, 23)
        Me.txtFileName.TabIndex = 3
        Me.txtFileName.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'btnPump
        '
        Me.btnPump.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(138, 269)
        Me.btnPump.Name = "btnPump"
        Me.btnPump.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.btnPump.TabIndex = 2
        Me.btnPump.Text = "Pump!"
        Me.btnPump.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'btnBrowse
        '
        Me.btnBrowse.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(302, 17)
        Me.btnBrowse.Name = "btnBrowse"
        Me.btnBrowse.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.btnBrowse.TabIndex = 1
        Me.btnBrowse.Text = "Browse..."
        Me.btnBrowse.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'NumericUpDown1
        '
        Me.NumericUpDown1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(245, 78)
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Maximum = New Decimal(New Integer() {500, 0, 0, 0})
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Minimum = New Decimal(New Integer() {10, 0, 0, 0})
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Name = "NumericUpDown1"
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(120, 20)
        Me.NumericUpDown1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.NumericUpDown1.Value = New Decimal(New Integer() {10, 0, 0, 0})
        '
        'Binder
        '
        Me.Binder.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox2)
        Me.Binder.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
        Me.Binder.Controls.Add(Me.btn_Bind)
        Me.Binder.Controls.Add(Me.btn_File1)
        Me.Binder.Controls.Add(Me.btn_File2)
        Me.Binder.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 4)
        Me.Binder.Name = "Binder"
        Me.Binder.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(383, 311)
        Me.Binder.TabIndex = 2
        Me.Binder.Text = "Binder"
        Me.Binder.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'IconChanger
        '
        Me.IconChanger.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 4)
        Me.IconChanger.Name = "IconChanger"
        Me.IconChanger.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(383, 311)
        Me.IconChanger.TabIndex = 3
        Me.IconChanger.Text = "Icon Changer"
        Me.IconChanger.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'About
        '
        Me.About.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel3)
        Me.About.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel2)
        Me.About.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel1)
        Me.About.Controls.Add(Me.MetroButton1)
        Me.About.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(124, 4)
        Me.About.Name = "About"
        Me.About.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(383, 311)
        Me.About.TabIndex = 5
        Me.About.Text = "About"
        Me.About.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        '
        'MetroLabel3
        '
        Me.MetroLabel3.AutoSize = true
        Me.MetroLabel3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(110, 247)
        Me.MetroLabel3.Name = "MetroLabel3"
        Me.MetroLabel3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(143, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel3.TabIndex = 3
        Me.MetroLabel3.Text = "Made by: X9Gaming01"
        '
        'MetroLabel2
        '
        Me.MetroLabel2.AutoSize = true
        Me.MetroLabel2.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Small
        Me.MetroLabel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(29, 40)
        Me.MetroLabel2.Name = "MetroLabel2"
        Me.MetroLabel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(326, 15)
        Me.MetroLabel2.TabIndex = 2
        Me.MetroLabel2.Text = "DECrypt - A free Crypter, File Pumper, Binder and Icon Changer!"
        '
        'MetroLabel1
        '
        Me.MetroLabel1.AutoSize = true
        Me.MetroLabel1.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Tall
        Me.MetroLabel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(142, 15)
        Me.MetroLabel1.Name = "MetroLabel1"
        Me.MetroLabel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 25)
        Me.MetroLabel1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.MetroLabel1.Text = "DECrypt"
        '
        'MetroButton1
        '
        Me.MetroButton1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(133, 269)
        Me.MetroButton1.Name = "MetroButton1"
        Me.MetroButton1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(92, 23)
        Me.MetroButton1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.MetroButton1.Text = "Donate <3"
        Me.MetroButton1.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'btn_File2
        '
        Me.btn_File2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(322, 63)
        Me.btn_File2.Name = "btn_File2"
        Me.btn_File2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 23)
        Me.btn_File2.TabIndex = 0
        Me.btn_File2.Text = "File 2"
        Me.btn_File2.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'btn_File1
        '
        Me.btn_File1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(322, 25)
        Me.btn_File1.Name = "btn_File1"
        Me.btn_File1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 23)
        Me.btn_File1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.btn_File1.Text = "File 1"
        Me.btn_File1.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'btn_Bind
        '
        Me.btn_Bind.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(160, 269)
        Me.btn_Bind.Name = "btn_Bind"
        Me.btn_Bind.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.btn_Bind.TabIndex = 2
        Me.btn_Bind.Text = "Bind!"
        Me.btn_Bind.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'TextBox1
        '
        Me.TextBox1.Lines = New String(-1) {}
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 25)
        Me.TextBox1.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
        Me.TextBox1.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0)
        Me.TextBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.TextBox1.SelectedText = ""
        Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 23)
        Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 3
        Me.TextBox1.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'TextBox2
        '
        Me.TextBox2.Lines = New String(-1) {}
        Me.TextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 63)
        Me.TextBox2.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.TextBox2.Name = "TextBox2"
        Me.TextBox2.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0)
        Me.TextBox2.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.TextBox2.SelectedText = ""
        Me.TextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 23)
        Me.TextBox2.TabIndex = 4
        Me.TextBox2.UseSelectable = true
        '
        'main
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(512, 382)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Ctc1)
        Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"),System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.MaximizeBox = false
        Me.Name = "main"
        Me.Resizable = false
        Me.Text = "DECrypt"
        Me.TextAlign = MetroFramework.Forms.MetroFormTextAlign.Center
        Me.Ctc1.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.FilePumper.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.FilePumper.PerformLayout
        CType(Me.NumericUpDown1,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit
        Me.Binder.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.About.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.About.PerformLayout
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)

End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Ctc1 As CTC
    Friend WithEvents Crypter As TabPage
    Friend WithEvents FilePumper As TabPage
    Friend WithEvents Binder As TabPage
    Friend WithEvents IconChanger As TabPage
    Friend WithEvents About As TabPage
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel3 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroButton1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents rbtnMegaByte As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroRadioButton
    Friend WithEvents rbtnKiloByte As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroRadioButton
    Friend WithEvents txtFileName As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents btnPump As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents btnBrowse As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents NumericUpDown1 As NumericUpDown
    Friend WithEvents TextBox2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents btn_Bind As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents btn_File1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents btn_File2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
End Class
```

If anyone knows why this is happening or how to fix it I would really love it.

If you need anymore information just ask and I will give you what you need to hopefully resolve my issue.

Comment: it might help to know which is Line 115

Comment: Me.rbtnKiloByte.UseSelectable = true
is the 115 line

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line in question.  The example above has “The designer cannot process the code at line 115” so comment out Line 115.  Then open the file.  It would behoove you to look at why that line is causing the error in the first place.  Check if it was “manually modified” as the error message suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old and you might have resolved this by now, but I ran into a similar issue using MetroFrameWork. Everything was working fine, I saved and closed. Upon re-opening the project, error in the designer.

I don't know for sure what is causing the issue, but I know how to resolve it :)

It seems, randomly, a line of code is added in the designer, something like:

```
Me.*nameofthecomponent*.Lines = New String(-1) {}
```

In your code, at line 119, you have:

```
Me.txtFileName.Lines = New String(-1) {}
```

So the trick is to simply delete that line. Whatever line the designer says it's unable to process, just look at the next un-commented line, you shall find the culprit.

In your above code, you have other occurrences at lines:

- 262
- 275

Hope that helps :)