# The designer cannot process the code at line (line)

Tags: vb.net, designer, visual-studio-2015, java-metro-framework

I was working on a VB.net project and at one point, I could not edit the design of any form due to this error:

> The designer cannot process the code at line 259, please see the Task List for details.  The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

It was working just fine before and I made no changes to the forms themselves.
The only modification I made to this file was adding

```
Inherits MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
```

And removing that and replacing it with the original System.Windows.Forms.Form did not solve the problem.

Here is one of the form's code:

```
 <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
    Partial Class Config
    Inherits MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    'Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.TTime = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.MetroLabel1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroLabel2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroPanel1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel()
        Me.MetroLabel3 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroPanel2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel()
        Me.MetroLabel4 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroLabel5 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.BlackoutFrom = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox()
        Me.BlackoutTo = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox()
        Me.MetroLabel6 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroPanel3 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel()
        Me.MetroLabel7 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MinBox = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.MetroLabel8 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroButton1 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.MetroButton2 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.MetroButton3 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.PasswordBox = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox()
        Me.MetroLabel9 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel()
        Me.MetroButton4 = New MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton()
        Me.MetroToolTip1 = New MetroFramework.Components.MetroToolTip()
        Me.MetroPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.MetroPanel2.SuspendLayout()
        Me.MetroPanel3.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'TTime
        '
        Me.TTime.Lines = New String() {"0"}
        Me.TTime.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(87, 33)
        Me.TTime.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.TTime.Name = "TTime"
        Me.TTime.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0)
        Me.TTime.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.TTime.SelectedText = ""
        Me.TTime.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(32, 23)
        Me.TTime.TabIndex = 0
        Me.TTime.Text = "0"
        Me.TTime.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroLabel1
        '
        Me.MetroLabel1.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 34)
        Me.MetroLabel1.Name = "MetroLabel1"
        Me.MetroLabel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.MetroLabel1.Text = "Time Limit:"
        '
        'MetroLabel2
        '
        Me.MetroLabel2.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(126, 33)
        Me.MetroLabel2.Name = "MetroLabel2"
        Me.MetroLabel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel2.TabIndex = 2
        Me.MetroLabel2.Text = "Hours"
        '
        'MetroPanel1
        '
        Me.MetroPanel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.MetroPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel3)
        Me.MetroPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel2)
        Me.MetroPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel1)
        Me.MetroPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TTime)
        Me.MetroPanel1.HorizontalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel1.HorizontalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel1.HorizontalScrollbarSize = 10
        Me.MetroPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 78)
        Me.MetroPanel1.Name = "MetroPanel1"
        Me.MetroPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(186, 75)
        Me.MetroPanel1.TabIndex = 3
        Me.MetroPanel1.VerticalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel1.VerticalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel1.VerticalScrollbarSize = 10
        '
        'MetroLabel3
        '
        Me.MetroLabel3.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel3.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Tall
        Me.MetroLabel3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(36, 0)
        Me.MetroLabel3.Name = "MetroLabel3"
        Me.MetroLabel3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(113, 25)
        Me.MetroLabel3.TabIndex = 4
        Me.MetroLabel3.Text = "Time Settings"
        '
        'MetroPanel2
        '
        Me.MetroPanel2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.MetroPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.BlackoutTo)
        Me.MetroPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel6)
        Me.MetroPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.BlackoutFrom)
        Me.MetroPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel5)
        Me.MetroPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel4)
        Me.MetroPanel2.HorizontalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel2.HorizontalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel2.HorizontalScrollbarSize = 10
        Me.MetroPanel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(23, 159)
        Me.MetroPanel2.Name = "MetroPanel2"
        Me.MetroPanel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(186, 121)
        Me.MetroPanel2.TabIndex = 4
        Me.MetroPanel2.VerticalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel2.VerticalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel2.VerticalScrollbarSize = 10
        '
        'MetroLabel4
        '
        Me.MetroLabel4.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel4.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Tall
        Me.MetroLabel4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 0)
        Me.MetroLabel4.Name = "MetroLabel4"
        Me.MetroLabel4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(140, 25)
        Me.MetroLabel4.TabIndex = 5
        Me.MetroLabel4.Text = "Blackout Settings"
        '
        'MetroLabel5
        '
        Me.MetroLabel5.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(36, 39)
        Me.MetroLabel5.Name = "MetroLabel5"
        Me.MetroLabel5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(41, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel5.TabIndex = 6
        Me.MetroLabel5.Text = "From"
        '
        'BlackoutFrom
        '
        Me.BlackoutFrom.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.BlackoutFrom.ItemHeight = 23
        Me.BlackoutFrom.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"})
        Me.BlackoutFrom.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(83, 35)
        Me.BlackoutFrom.Name = "BlackoutFrom"
        Me.BlackoutFrom.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 29)
        Me.BlackoutFrom.TabIndex = 7
        Me.BlackoutFrom.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'BlackoutTo
        '
        Me.BlackoutTo.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.BlackoutTo.ItemHeight = 23
        Me.BlackoutTo.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"})
        Me.BlackoutTo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(83, 71)
        Me.BlackoutTo.Name = "BlackoutTo"
        Me.BlackoutTo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 29)
        Me.BlackoutTo.TabIndex = 9
        Me.BlackoutTo.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroLabel6
        '
        Me.MetroLabel6.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(55, 76)
        Me.MetroLabel6.Name = "MetroLabel6"
        Me.MetroLabel6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(22, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel6.TabIndex = 8
        Me.MetroLabel6.Text = "To"
        '
        'MetroPanel3
        '
        Me.MetroPanel3.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MetroButton3)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MetroButton2)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MetroButton1)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel8)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MinBox)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel7)
        Me.MetroPanel3.HorizontalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel3.HorizontalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel3.HorizontalScrollbarSize = 10
        Me.MetroPanel3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(221, 159)
        Me.MetroPanel3.Name = "MetroPanel3"
        Me.MetroPanel3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 121)
        Me.MetroPanel3.TabIndex = 5
        Me.MetroPanel3.VerticalScrollbarBarColor = True
        Me.MetroPanel3.VerticalScrollbarHighlightOnWheel = False
        Me.MetroPanel3.VerticalScrollbarSize = 10
        '
        'MetroLabel7
        '
        Me.MetroLabel7.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel7.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Tall
        Me.MetroLabel7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(48, 0)
        Me.MetroLabel7.Name = "MetroLabel7"
        Me.MetroLabel7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(106, 25)
        Me.MetroLabel7.TabIndex = 5
        Me.MetroLabel7.Text = "Modify Time"
        '
        'MinBox
        '
        Me.MinBox.Lines = New String() {"30"}
        Me.MinBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(92, 29)
        Me.MinBox.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.MinBox.Name = "MinBox"
        Me.MinBox.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0)
        Me.MinBox.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.MinBox.SelectedText = ""
        Me.MinBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.MinBox.TabIndex = 6
        Me.MinBox.Text = "30"
        Me.MinBox.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroLabel8
        '
        Me.MetroLabel8.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(29, 31)
        Me.MetroLabel8.Name = "MetroLabel8"
        Me.MetroLabel8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel8.TabIndex = 7
        Me.MetroLabel8.Text = "Minutes:"
        '
        'MetroButton1
        '
        Me.MetroButton1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(48, 58)
        Me.MetroButton1.Name = "MetroButton1"
        Me.MetroButton1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 23)
        Me.MetroButton1.TabIndex = 8
        Me.MetroButton1.Text = "Add"
        Me.MetroButton1.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroButton2
        '
        Me.MetroButton2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(97, 58)
        Me.MetroButton2.Name = "MetroButton2"
        Me.MetroButton2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 23)
        Me.MetroButton2.TabIndex = 9
        Me.MetroButton2.Text = "Remove"
        Me.MetroButton2.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroButton3
        '
        Me.MetroButton3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(48, 87)
        Me.MetroButton3.Name = "MetroButton3"
        Me.MetroButton3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(99, 23)
        Me.MetroButton3.TabIndex = 10
        Me.MetroButton3.Text = "Reset Timer"
        Me.MetroButton3.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'PasswordBox
        '
        Me.PasswordBox.Lines = New String(-1) {}
        Me.PasswordBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(214, 293)
        Me.PasswordBox.MaxLength = 32767
        Me.PasswordBox.Name = "PasswordBox"
        Me.PasswordBox.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(9679)
        Me.PasswordBox.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None
        Me.PasswordBox.SelectedText = ""
        Me.PasswordBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 23)
        Me.PasswordBox.TabIndex = 6
        Me.PasswordBox.UseSelectable = True
        Me.PasswordBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        '
        'MetroLabel9
        '
        Me.MetroLabel9.AutoSize = True
        Me.MetroLabel9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(143, 295)
        Me.MetroLabel9.Name = "MetroLabel9"
        Me.MetroLabel9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(66, 19)
        Me.MetroLabel9.TabIndex = 7
        Me.MetroLabel9.Text = "Password:"
        '
        'MetroButton4
        '
        Me.MetroButton4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(176, 322)
        Me.MetroButton4.Name = "MetroButton4"
        Me.MetroButton4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(84, 23)
        Me.MetroButton4.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Silver
        Me.MetroButton4.TabIndex = 8
        Me.MetroButton4.Text = "Save and Exit"
        Me.MetroButton4.UseSelectable = True
        '
        'MetroToolTip1
        '
        Me.MetroToolTip1.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Blue
        Me.MetroToolTip1.StyleManager = Nothing
        Me.MetroToolTip1.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Light
        '
        'Config
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(444, 362)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MetroButton4)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MetroLabel9)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PasswordBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MetroPanel3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MetroPanel2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MetroPanel1)
        Me.Name = "Config"
        Me.Resizable = False
        Me.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Purple
        Me.Text = "Configuration"
        Me.MetroPanel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.MetroPanel1.PerformLayout()
        Me.MetroPanel2.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.MetroPanel2.PerformLayout()
        Me.MetroPanel3.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.MetroPanel3.PerformLayout()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents TTime As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroPanel1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel3 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroPanel2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel4 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel5 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents BlackoutFrom As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox
    Friend WithEvents BlackoutTo As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel6 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroPanel3 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel7 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroButton2 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents MetroButton1 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel8 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MinBox As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents MetroButton3 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents PasswordBox As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    Friend WithEvents MetroLabel9 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel
    Friend WithEvents MetroButton4 As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton
    Friend WithEvents MetroToolTip1 As MetroFramework.Components.MetroToolTip
End Class
```

Line 259 is this:

```
Me.MetroButton3.UseSelectable = True
```

This also happened to another form in the same project.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you install the MetroFrameWork with NuGet?

Comment: @436f6465786572 At first I did, but i'm now referencing the DLL's

Comment: This actually has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921384/the-designer-cannot-process-the-code-at-line-115-please-see-the-task-list-for-d . Same issue but never answered. Im digging into this.

Comment: Make sure a reference to MetroFramework.dll and MetroFramework.Design.dll. The latter is for design-time support and doesn't need to be deployed, i.e. you should set the "Copy Local" property to false.
Due to the non-intrusive installation procedure, support for creating your first form isn't optimal. The recommended procedure is to add a new "Windows Form" to your project. Then press F7 to switch into code view and change the base class from "Form" to "MetroFramework.Forms.Form". Switch back to design view and you should be able to add more MetroFramework controls from the Toolbox as usual.

Comment: When you do this it add the needed dependencies...

Comment: @436f6465786572 That's what I did with Config (The code I showed above), it worked for a while and then displayed the error. I've discovered something interesting though. If I copy and paste the code from the Config form and paste it into a new form (changing the header to the new form's name) it throws the same error. So it may be something with how Visual Studio adds elements, and maybe it made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: it is possible. As said in another comment, when you install it using the NuGet it add required dependencies. The only thing you have to do then, is change what the form inherits and that is it. I am not sure what you may have done, but it doesn't like it.

Comment: @436f6465786572 That's basically what I did. I don't recall ever changing the design file besides for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to another question.  Anyway, comment out the line in question.  The example above has “The designer cannot process the code at line 259” so comment out line 259.  Then open the file in the designer view.  You'll want to look at why that line is causing the error in the first place and/or if commenting it out causes new problems.  Check if it was “manually modified” as the error message suggests.

Comment: I eventually found the solution by commenting line by line until I found this line 'Me.PasswordBox.Lines = New String(-1) {}' which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same Problem and i solved this with Downloading the 600 MB  Visual Studio 2012 (which i used for my Projects before) and works perfect!
This new Visual Studio 2015 is messed up and seems Buggy, so download the full express Version (i got the iso file and unpack with winrar and installed)
Problem solved, i got the Problem on 4 mashines, now all work with my older codes :-)
Peace
Babas